# IF EXISTS UPDATE ELSE INSERT using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

We are developing an application for our college and in the fees module we need to check whether the student record is already present. If the student record does not exist we need to insert the record else we need to update the record.The code i have used is listed below:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['mca_1_autogen_id']); ++$i){
   $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `fees_mca_1` set `Fees_paid`='{$_POST['Fp'][$i]}' where Register_number='{{$_POST['Regno'][$i]}'");
}
header("Location:mca1_fees_report.php");
 if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) == 0){
 for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['mca_1_autogen_id']); ++$i){
   $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `fees_mca_1`(`Register_number`,`Student_name`,`Total_fees`,`Fees_paid`) VALUES ('{$_POST['Regno'][$i]}','{$_POST['Sname'][$i]}','{$_POST['Fees'][$i]}','{$_POST['Fp'][$i]}')") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc));
}}
header("Location:mca1_fees_report.php");
echo "Record Added Sucessfully";
 }
```

I have also tried this but no avail

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['mca_1_autogen_id']); ++$i){
   $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `fees_mca_1`(`Register_number`,`Student_name`,`Total_fees`,`Fees_paid`) VALUES ('{$_POST['Regno'][$i]}','{$_POST['Sname'][$i]}','{$_POST['Fees'][$i]}','{$_POST['Fp'][$i]}') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Fees_paid` = VALUES({$_POST['Fp'][$i]})");
}
header("Location:mca1_fees_report.php");
echo "Record Added Sucessfully";
  }
```

Comment: did you check `ON DUPLICATE KEY` in mysql?

Answer (score 2):

You should use this instead:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

UPDATE t1 SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;
```

It will check if the record is duplicated, then it will update it

Here is the 
[Official Link to Sql Query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) .

Also please check `ON DUPLICATE KEY`

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this:

```
INSERT INTO table(column_list)  VALUES(value_list) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column_1 = new_value_1, column_2 = new_value_2, …;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);